# Similarity API with one string, and a list of strings

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

The academic smilarity api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Academic-Knowledge/SimilarityMethod

It takes two strings. For example, string 1: "Backpack" and string 2: "Accessory". However I want string 2 to be a list of potential words, is this possible with this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Referring to the document, the API only accepts String data type. So you cannot use a list type. But you can write a function in which you can separate the potential words into single string, and call the API for every string.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid calling API for every string because i have 100 strings I want to compare a word to. that's 100 calls :(

Comment: Its not supported unfortunately. You could try my work around.

Comment: Thanks man for the fast reply. Do you know of any similar service? Maybe competing service to Azure? Like Google or AWS? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The 100s of calls will get expensive. :(

Comment: I understand API calling will be costly here. I am extremely sorry that I am not very expert on AWS or Google Cloud. Pardon me please.

Comment: No problem brother, thank you very much for trying.

Comment: I come to know no way out except iterate through it which is costly as it is API request format.

Comment: Thanks Md Farid, it does answer the question that it is not possible. But I still have the problem. :(  I'll accept anyways though, thanks for your time.